# Do I need slashes before links?

Tags: html

When I code my website, on my local computer i can use

```
 <a href="index.html">blablabla</a>.
```

However, I also can see this type of thing on other places as
    <`a href="/index.html">blablabla</a>.`
I am not sure what I will need when my site goes live. If I try to do this on my local computer, it doesn't understand it. My question is, if I post my site up like this, will it work?

Ok, if I have all of the files of my site in the root directory that the main index.html file is located in, will it work when it is being hosted?

Comment: / points to the root of your site - the same place, no matter which subfolder you're currently in. Without / it will try to load the page from your current location

Comment: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: If all your files are in one root directory - no need to add slash, keep the links as it is - relative. This will help in the future, should you need to put them all into a subfolder - the relative links will still work

Comment: Ok thank you! I just started htmling about 2 wks ago and this really helped!

Comment: @user3417054 in that case, visit http://htmldog.com/ for some good tutorials.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not use a slash, the link will point to `index.html` in the same folder as the page the link is on.

For example, if you have a link to `index.html` on the page `www.example.com/page2.html` then the link will take you to `www.example.com/index.html`. If you include a slash, it will do the same thing.

However, if the link is in a page in a subfolder, like `www.example.com/projects/page2.html`, then the first link will take you to `www.example.com/projects/index.html` while the second link will still take you to `www.example.com/index.html`.

The slash denotes the "web root."

Note that these are still considered "relative" links: they refer to a resource on the same server, regardless of the server's name. If your domain name changes or you upload it to another server, relative links will still work provided they have the same folder structure.